# prevent manipulation of JWT token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I am trying to verify that somene if changed the JWT token from browser .The user should logout.

authorisedUser has  some fields like username,id. 
My code  is working for only the case when any of this is changed and user is getting logged out.

But if i replaced this with another valid authorisedUser ,user is not logged out

So user A can user user B cookie and have access to his data.How should i change below code to verify it.

This is a light weight application so use of session or database is not there.

```
          jwt.verify(req.cookies["authorisedUser"], "shhhhh", function (err, payload) {
             if (err) {

          res.redirect(db.env.application.logout_url+'?error=true');
          //res.redirect(db.env.application.logout_url);
                   }
           else{

           //normal code}}
```

Comment: Have look at https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript/2019-03-29-node-jwt-authentication/

Comment: This is how it works! If someone steals you cookie then he might get access to your account. And this a FACT!